# logback java - log.error works but log.info doesn't

Tags: java, spring, logback

I have a web application on java spring mvc 4. I'm using logback 1.2.3 for logging. It happens:

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleController.class);

On controller method:

```
LOG.info("The info"); // Prints nothing
LOG.error("The error"); // It prints on log file
```

I'm giving you logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <property name="LOG_PATH" value="${catalina.base}/logs/app" /> 
  <property name="LOG_NAME" value="app" />

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/${LOG_NAME}.log</file>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/archived/${LOG_NAME}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>5</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>

    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %t %c:%L - %m%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %t %c:%L - %m%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
  <root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

What is it missing?

Comment: You duplicated the root logger declaration. Remove the öné where you defined the error lóg level.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add one block

```
<root level="INFO">
  <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```

for your `ref="STDOUT". level="INFO"` means that you print all log with `level >= INFO`

So can you try to remove the second one because it probably overrides the first one

```
<root level="ERROR">
  <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```

Comment: It's working. Thanks. According to http://logback.qos.ch/manual/architecture.html the level order is TRACE < DEBUG < INFO <  WARN < ERROR. I removed the second root level and the app prints log.error and log.info. I'm understanding the app will print info, warn, error. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes @user3637971 exactly the app will print info, warn, error if the level is info